# SQL Server synonyms with concurrent execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, synonym

I work in a DW project where we do ETL using T-SQL with SQL Server 2012. Our code works well so far for a set of tables coming from a legacy system. However, the Data Architect has announced we will receive tables from other legacy systems. He wants the same piece of code to be able to handle all the tables of all the systems since they will have the same structure but exist in separate DBs in the same server.

On top of that, he requires the existing piece of code to run at the same time for all of the system's tables so we save execution time. I have been working on a POC using synonyms which seems to do the trick but it won't execute our code for different set of tables at the same time because we will end up overwriting the references of the synonym objects currently being executed. So I am now rethinking the whole problem: How to avoid rewriting the same code we have for each set of tables we get while at the same time allowing concurrent execution? Any insight or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using SSIS to do your ETL. You can change the location of the source data at run time and as long as the structure is the same it should work.

Comment: Your suggestion is interesting and I will take a deeper look at SSIS. My boss do not want to use SSIS because we are doing SCD type 4 (data changes goes to auditing tables) and SSIS does not support that as far as we have seen. Perhaps there is a way in SSIS of doing it without using their SCD controls.

Comment: If it were me and that were the requirement (i.e. audit changes), I'd either use CDC and process the changes into another table or use a trigger and do the same. Either way, let the ETL be an ETL and not an "ETL and audit".